# How do I get PowerShell to delete entire rows for all .xls files in folder?

Tags: powershell, xls

I have .xls files in a folder, and I would like to format each file with PowerShell in an identical manner as follows:

- delete Row 1, and shift cells up
- delete Row 2, and shift cells up
- again, delete Row 2, and shift cells up
- finally, one last time, delete Row 2, and shift cells up

In effect, I am deleting Row 1, then deleting Row 2 thrice. I'd like to save each file with original filename, close, and quit.

This is what I have:

```
Name    Time    in    out



Miami   07:00   50    100
```

And this is what I would like:

```
Name    Time    in    out
Miami   07:00   50    100
```

Here is the correct script [after great feedback from others]:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$excel.Visible = $false
$localPath = (Get-Location).ToString()
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem *.xls) {
    $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file.FullName)
    $wb.WorkSheets.Item(1).Range("A3:A5").EntireRow.Delete() # deletes Rows 3,4,5
    $wb.WorkSheets.Item(1).Range("A1").EntireRow.Delete() # deletes Row 1
    $wb.SaveAs($localPath + "\" + $file.Name)
    $wb.Close($true)
}
$excel.Quit()
[void][Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
```

Comment: I suspect you're not finding any *.xls files and therefore never entering the foreach loop. Rather than searching in your working directory, maybe try hardcoding or passing in as a parameter the directory you want to search for .xls files.  And/or include a Write-Output $file within the for loop to be sure you're actually finding the files.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the ranges from the WorkSheet rather than the workbook? As far as I know, its Excel > WorkBook > Worksheet and every Workbook as a default Worksheet.

Comment: @Shadowzee: I've been running the script line by line, and there seems to be a problem in the way I selected the range of cells to delete, that is `$range1 = $wb.Range("A1","D1")`. What I am trying to is select and delete the first four cells in Row 1. For that matter, I might as well delete the entire Row 1 for the desired result.

Comment: I'd recommend deleting rows from the bottom up. Keeps your offsets stable. As for deleting rows, something like this should do: `$wb.Range("A1:A2").EntireRow.Delete()`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Thanks, Ansgar. Will `$wb.Range("A1:A2").EntireRow.Delete()` delete Row 1 and Row 2 simultaneously, or delete Row 1 first, shift cells up, and then delete Row 2?

Comment: Both rows will be deleted in one step, same as if you marked two rows and then deleted them.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Since my blank rows in the first table above are Rows 1,3,4,5, should I do `$wb.Range("A1:A3:A4:A5").EntireRow.Delete()`?

Comment: No, range strings don't work that way. Do `$wb.Range("A3:A5").EntireRow.Delete(); $wb.Range("A1").EntireRow.Delete()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185444/discussion-between-ahr-and-ansgar-wiechers).